# In MVC While adding form is doing postback fine. But When Editing same from Submit button is not working. Its Not hitting Controller Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my part of code . Here i can add and submit the values. But while editing submit is not working. Can anyone help me on this. What can be the Issue over here.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LenseAdd", "Stock", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-bordered" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LenseId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MaterialId)

            <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Lense Code<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    @*<input type="text" class="form-control" />*@
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LenseCode, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Lense Code", @id = "LenseCode" })
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-money"></span></span>
                                </div>
                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LenseCode, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-sm-3">BrandName<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BrandId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BrandList, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlbranchId" })
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-money"></span></span>
                                </div>
                                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SalaryTo, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @if (Model != null)
                            {
                                if (Model.CategoryList != null)
                                {
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Material</label>
                                    foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
                                    {
                                        if (item.CategoryName == "MATERIAL")
                                        {
                                            <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="c-form__group -radio -inline">
                                                    <label class="c-form__control-text radio_heading">
                                                        <label>@item.Name</label>

                                                        @if (Model.MaterialId == item.ID)
                                                        {
                                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MaterialId, true, new { @checked = "checked", @class = "MATERIAL", @id = "MATERIAL_"+item.ID.ToString() })
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MaterialId, false, new { @class = "MATERIAL", @id = "MATERIAL_" + item.ID.ToString() })
                                                        }
                                                        <div class="-indicator"></div>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        </div>

 <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 text-right">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom fa fa-save -blue" >Save & New</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom fa fa-save -skyblue" id="btn_submit">Save</button>
                            <a href="@Url.Content("~/Stock/List")" class="btn btn-custom fa fa-times -yellow">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

I didn't copy the full cshtml page. here if you see any div mismatching please ignore. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have two submit buttons.  They should both do the exact same thing, because a submit will only submit to the form method provided, there is no difference here between them.  If one button is not working, i'm guessing you have some javascript that is doing something to disable it (or causing an error which would also cause nothing to happen).

Comment: I kept two button for different purpose. for now i make both of them submit. While adding new both buttons are working. i can submit through any of these. but in editing none of them are working.